# What is wrong with this condition ? only the last else condition always execute

Tags: java, android

Have 3 buttons for time pickers with the below condition to set the time on the button but only the last condition always turn true....can't figure out why?

```
if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    } else
        button4.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
```

Comment: please post more of the code where "view" and "R.id.button*" are defined

Comment: If you have already initialized  `Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)`; and others then don't need to initialize it again. Also check that all buttons have click method implementation.

Comment: It simply means that `view.getId()==R.id.button1` and `view.getId()==R.id.button2` are not true :)

Comment: The above is not under the onclick() method but rather...under the onTimeSet() method.....

Comment: Where does `view` come from?

Comment: @sadiksmart based on your comment - the view will always be the `TimePicker` view - not any buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As per coding part, if and only if your both upper conditions false and criteria other than if and else if condition then only 3rd condition will get executed.
So identify based on it.

If you can give me details about buttons IDs and what ID you are looking for then I can able to give exact answer.

Thanks

Comment: public class TimePickerFragment extends 
    DialogFragment implements 
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
        @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle 
    savedInstanceState){
    final Calendar c =
    Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

Comment: return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,true);}
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){

    if(view.getId()==R.id.button1){
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);}

   else if(view.getId()==R.id.button2){
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
}
    else
button4.setText (hourOfDay+":"+minute);

}
share

Comment: @sadiksmart Please edit that code into your question; it is impossible to read here.